# Is this piece of jquery ajax code correct?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am making a simple web chat application using ajax,php,javascript and mysql.
What I am trying to do here is to avoid fetching the whole database after an interval of 1 sec(which is normally done in basic chat application ) but rather I want to fetch and display(by appending) also those chats which have been newly entered into the database by any user.

To implement this ,First when the user first opens the chat screen the whole database is loaded in the chat window(not shown in this code snippet),and then I am using the variable msgid to fetch the latest value of MSg_ID (which is the auto-increment primary key in my chat table) through an ajax request to the page 'Msg.php' which returns the required value of msg_id.

Now using this value of msgid and comparing it with the max value of Msg_ID every second in the database through the ajax request to the page 'Chat3.php'.
If the Max value of Msg_ID has changed the required rows are returned . After this I m updating the value of 'msgid' using the same earlier ajax request to the page 'Msg.php'

The pages Msg.php and Chat3.php are working perfectly ,as I have tested them thoroughly.

My question here is what is the problem in my code , why is not working?
Can we use an ajax request inside a ajax call back function or not?
What else can be a probable source of error?
Any input will be valuable :)
If you have any problem in understanding the code,leave a comment.
'#yyy' and '#zzz' are random div elements which i am using to test the data value of ajax callback function.

I can even post the rest of the code if it helps.

```
 <script type"text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
        var dept = '<?php echo $deptId; ?>';

        $.ajax({
                url: 'scripts/php/Msg.php',
                data: {dept:dept},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#yyy').html(data);//this displays the correct value
                var msgid=data;
            }
        });

        var interval = setInterval(function() { 
        $.ajax({
                url: 'scripts/php/Chat3.php',
                data: {dept:dept,msgid:msgid},
                success: function(data) {   
                    if(data!='bad'){    
                        //$('#messages').prepend(data);
                        $('#zzz').html(data);//does not display any value although Chat3.php is returning the correct value.
                        //below ajax request to update the value of msgid
                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'scripts/php/Msg.php',
                        data: {dept:dept},
                        success: function(data) {
                        var msgid=data;
                        $('#zzz').html(data);   //not displaying anything although above one is was displaying
                        }
                        });
                    }   
                }   
        });

    }, 1000);
     });
     </script>
```

Here is my Msg.php

```
  <?php
  require '../../includes/database/connect.db.php';
  function get_msg($dept){

    $query= "SELECT Msg_ID,Sender, Message ,Time_stamp FROM chat WHERE Dept_ID='$dept' ORDER BY Msg_ID DESC" ;
    $run=mysql_query($query);

    $messages =array();
    while($message=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
        $messages[] =array('msgid'=>$message['Msg_ID'],
                        'sender'=>$message['Sender'],
                           'message'=>$message['Message'],
                       'time_stamp'=>$message['Time_stamp']);
    }
    return $messages;
 }
 $dept=$_GET['dept'];
 $messages = get_msg($dept);

  $x=count($messages);
 if($x){
            foreach($messages as $message) {
              if($x==count($messages)){
                echo $message['msgid'];
            }
        $x--;
     }
  }     
 ?>
```

Here is my Chat3.php

```
<?php
     require '../../includes/database/connect.db.php';
     function get_msg($dept,$msgid){
     $query1= "SELECT MAX(Msg_ID) as msg_id FROM chat" ;
     $run1=mysql_query($query1);
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run1);
      $result =$row['msg_id'];

      $messages =array();
      if($result>$msgid)
      {
      $query= "SELECT Sender, Message ,Time_stamp FROM chat WHERE Dept_ID='$dept' AND Msg_ID>'$msgid' ORDER BY Msg_ID DESC" ;
      $run=mysql_query($query);

      while($message=mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
        $messages[] =array('sender'=>$message['Sender'],
                           'message'=>$message['Message'],
                         'time_stamp'=>$message['Time_stamp']);
      }
      return $messages;
     }
     else
     {
       return $messages;
     }
   }

  $dept=$_GET['dept'];
  $msgid=$_GET['msgid'];
   $messages = get_msg($dept,$msgid);

   if(count($messages)){
        foreach($messages as $message) {
            echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].' Sent</strong><br>';
            echo $message['message'].' <i><small><div       align="right">'.$message['time_stamp'].'</i></small></div>';
        }

  }     
  else {
  echo 'bad';
  }
?>
```

Comment: IF Msg.php and Chat3.php are working perfectly, what are the other errors that you are recieving?

Comment: No error is being generated, it is just it displaying the 'data'  element in the callback function, as if it is not recieving it or something, and I have completely checked My Msg.php and Chat3.php

Comment: Just for a notice, the type of ajax request you're making is a GET type, since nothing else declared, so if you're getting for post data, then you have to set type: 'POST' in the object.

Comment: I am using Get data only

Comment: Is this javascript generated by a PHP script and then echo'd out to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `msgid`

In your first AJAX Request you are setting the variable `var msgid=data;` which is in local scope.

I think you are trying to access that variable in the second `AJAX` request while sending the datas

```
url: 'scripts/php/Chat3.php',
data: {dept:dept,msgid:msgid}, // Trying to access the local variable of previous ajax request
```

**EDIT:**

Try removing the `var` from `var msgid=data;` in your first `AJAX` request. Removing `var` will make the variable `GLOBAL`, Although its not good to pollute the global scope, but you can definitely try out this for the time being

Comment: Yep that did the trick :) I did not know that javascript is also having locality of scope like c++ and other languages

Comment: `JS` do have scopes :)